# data and salt argument with bcrypt

Tags: node.js, express, bcrypt, saltedhash

I used the same module for every one of my subscriptions but I don't why with this one I have this  Error: data and salt arguments required
with a code 500.

maybe there is an update? But I can't find anything about that ...
also my code

```
inscription: (req, res, next) => {
    const emailVerif = RegExp("([A-z]|[0-9])+@([A-z]|[0-9])+.[A-z]{2,3}");
    const passwordVerif = RegExp(
      "^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-]).{8,}$"
    );

    /*stockage d'un mot de passe crypté dans la base de données apres le req*/

    var salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);
    const hash = bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password, salt);

    if (
      typeof req.body.restaurantName != "string" ||
      typeof req.body.bossFirstName != "string" ||
      typeof req.body.phone != "string" ||
      typeof req.body.bossName != "string" ||
      typeof req.body.adress != "string" ||
      emailVerif.test(req.body.email) == false
    ) {
      res.status(417);
      res.json({
        message:
          "Veuillez compléter les champs obligatoires et respecter le format de saisie.",
      });
    } else if (passwordVerif.test(req.body.password) == false) {
      res.status(417);
      res.json({
        message:
          "Votre mot de passe doit comporter au minimum 8 caractères dont une minuscule, une majuscule, un chiffre et un caractère spécial.",
      });
    } else {
      /*TEST ENVOI MAIL*/
      let rand = new Array(10).fill("").reduce(
        (accumulator) =>
          accumulator +
          Math.random()
            .toString(36)
            .replace(/[^a-z]+/g, "")
            .substr(0, 5)
      );

      const newRestaurateur = new Restaurateur({
        restaurantName: req.body.restaurantName,
        bossFirstName: req.body.bossFirstName,
        phone: req.body.phone,
        email: req.body.email,
        password: hash /*mdp hashé*/,
        bossName: req.body.bossName,
        adress: req.body.adress,
        location: {
          longitude: req.body.longitude,
          latitude: req.body.latitude,
        },
```

Comment: `417` is a highly specialized HTTP status code. Don't use it in this case.

Comment: @O.Jones , ok but do you think their is any problem between 417 and my error ?

Comment: are you sure `req.body.password` is actually populated?

Comment: I console.log it and he's here